# how to insert user data simultaneously in realtime data base and auth using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I coded web registration form and I wanted to insert user data simultaneously in "realtime-database and authentication" using javascript , so I tried the code below but it won't work , I added to my html file firebase sdk , and scripts of firebase-app.js , firebase-database.js and firebase-auth.js also I enbaled email and password authentication.

```
var smname = document.getElementById('SMName');
var smemail = document.getElementById('SMEmail');
var smphone = document.getElementById('SMPohne');
var smpsw = document.getElementById('SMPsw');
var confsmpsw = document.getElementById('CSMNPsw');


//verify form function

function validate(){

var error_message = document.getElementById("error_message");
var text;

error_message.style.padding = "10px";
   if(smname.value.length < 2 || smname.value.length > 25)
   {      console.log('error');

      text = "Please Enter valid Name";
      error_message.innerHTML = text;
      return false;
   }

   var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
   if(!regex.test(smemail.value))
   {      
      console.log('error');
      text = "Please Enter valid Email";
      error_message.innerHTML = text;
      return false;
   }


   if(isNaN(smphone.value) || smphone.value.length != 10){
      text = "Please Enter valid Phone Number";
      error_message.innerHTML = text;
      return false;
   }
   if( smpsw.value.length < 4 || smpsw.value.length > 25 )
   {      console.log('error');

      text = "Please Enter valid Password";
      error_message.innerHTML = text;
      return false;
   }


   if(confsmpsw.value == "" || confsmpsw.value!= smpsw.value)
   {
      console.log('error');
      text = "Password is incorrect ";
      error_message.innerHTML = text;
      return false;
   }

else
{
var email = document.getElementById('SMEmail').value;
var password = document.getElementById('SMPsw').value;

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(response){
   console.log('succ');
   console.log(response);

firebase.database().ref('Supermarkets').push({
         Supermarket_Name:smname.value,
      Supermarket_email:email,
      Supermarket_phone:smphone.value,
      Supermarket_password:password
   })
   firebase.auth().signOut();
 smemail.value='';
 smphone.value='';
 smname.value='';
 smpsw.value='';
 alert("Form Submitted Successfully!");

  }).catch(function(error){
   var errorCode = error.code;
   var errorMessage = error.message; 
   console.log(errorCode);
   console.log(errorMessage);

 });


return true;

}//else


}//verify()
```

Comment: "it won't work" is hard to troubleshoot for us. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger, so you will have to tell us what exactly is going wrong. Which specific line in the code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thank you sir for your mark , I found problem in else statement " firebase code "

Comment: what's the error ? is function `signInWithEmailPassword` gets executed ? if not then what do you get the error. show your console log messages. if something appears there

Comment: there is no console error , when I excute it , the console.log('succ'); don't even appear on the console , and the data don't insert in real-time database and authenitication

Comment: you have to make sure that the else block is called, because it may be just that you never get to that part, if you are sure about it, you should have some stuff printed in the console, either yours (succ or fail) or some firebase errors if you have you have configure it wrong. so just check if the code is executed and show us what's in the console

Comment: there is no problem with else block , when I use alert out of the firebase code it works correctly , the problem is in firebase code I think